# How to have Solr inform me of the number of documents deleted when using a delete query?

Tags: solr

I'm submitting the following solr command to the update handler: `{"delete": {"query": "id: 1"}}`

This will delete a single document but could delete however many documents that may match a given query. For example, here is the response to the above command.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "rf": 1,
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 62
  }
}
```

I see no count in there. How can I have solr include the number of documents that were deleted as a result of this command? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is supported because deletion is not a real deletion in solr until you commit or the segments are merged.  So solr (or lucene in this case) doesn't return the deletion count.

Comment: You can however get a (usually good enough) approximation by running the query first to retrieve `numFound`, then issuing the commit. There's a race condition there (i.e. the count can change between the query and the delete), but in many cases it might not matter.